# PHP - Behavior of static variable declared in parent method, when called from various children

Tags: php, variables, inheritance, methods, static

Say I have a class...

```
class Parent {
    protected function foo() {
        static $x = 0;
        $x++;
        return $x;
    }
}
```

... and these two child classes:

```
class ChildOne extends Parent {
    public function bar() {
        echo $this->foo();
    }
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent {
    public function bar() {
        echo $this->foo();
    }
}
```

Even though there is only one static variable declared, both ChildOne and ChildTwo are keeping their own record of $x, so the following...

```
...
$childOne.bar();
$childTwo.bar();
```

... is producing the output '11' instead of '12'.

Question: Is it possible to ensure that all child classes are using the same static variable when calling a parent method? The solution would produce an output of '12' in the example above without implementing a class property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer leads me to believe this simply isn't possible. For future reference to others, here is what I implemented:

```
class Parent {
    static $x = 0;
    protected function getX() {
        self::$x++;
        return self::$x;
    }
}

class ChildOne extends Parent {
    public function bar() {
        echo $this->getX();
    }
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent {
    public function bar() {
        echo $this->getX();
    }
}

...
$childOne.bar();
$childTwo.bar();
```

Output is '12' as required, but had to implement the static class property.

Answer (score 0):

try referring to the parent. say getX() returns a string

```
class ChildTwo extends Parent {
    public function bar() {
        $tempOfX $parent->getX();
        echo($tempOfX);
    }
}
```